# An error related to Entity Framework, .NET4, MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I am new to this platform. So, I'm not familier with all the terminologies.
I'm getting the error message :

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'ERP.Models.OpeningBalance' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'AccountHeadId'.

Here I got a Model class 'OpeningBalance' in the project 'ERP'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ERP.Models.Account
{
    public class OpeningBalance
    {

        [Key]
        public int OpenningBalanceId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} cannot be left blank.")]
        [Display(Name = "Openning Balance Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "", DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
        public DateTime OpenningBalanceDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} cannot be left blank.")]
        [Display(Name = "AccountHeadId")]
        public int AccountHeadId { get; set; }
        public virtual ChartOfAccount ChartOfAccount { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Isn't the `public int AccountHeadId { get; set; }` is

> a navigation property with the name 'AccountHeadId'

?
The Source Error shows the lines from **Controller** :

```
    var openingBalances = db.OpeningBalances.Include(o => o.AccountHeadId);
    return View(openingBalances.ToList());
```

I searched a lot in web including all related ques in stackoverflow, then tried the following form:

```
var openingBalances = from o in db.OpeningBalances.Include(o=>o.AccountHeadId) select o;  
return View(openingBalances.ToList());
```

That didn't work too. Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AccountHeadId` property is not a navigational property. A navigational property should be of type another entity such as `ChartOfAccount` or entity collection such as `ICollection<ChartOfAccount>`.

If the scalar property `AccountHeadId` is associated with the navigational property `ChartOfAccount` Then include `ChartOfAccount` in your query.

```
var openingBalances = db.OpeningBalances.Include(o => o.ChartOfAccount);
```

You use the `Include` method to eager load related entities to avoid multiple round trips to the database. Primitive properties such as `AccountHeadId` will be loaded always when you retrieve the entity that contain such properties.